# Call to undefined method with Eloquent in Laravel5.1

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and experiencing the error

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::votes()

when storing the data.

Business model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Model
{
public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Vote');
    }
}
```

And then the form POST request to

```
$business = Business::where('business_area', $request->input('business_area'))->get();

        $vote = $business->votes()->create($request->all());

        return response()->json($vote, 201);
```

For some reason it cannot find the votes method. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Model is loaded.

ex

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the `Comment` model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with `_id`. So, for this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the `Comment model` is `post_id`.

[HasMany In Laravel](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question with the rest of the code in my model. Looks like only one difference in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

you can call votes on a single instance of model, not on the collection. so first foreach over $business, and then call votes on single instance.

Comment: Thank you! So in the view I need the two for each, first for business and then inside that one for votes? Just making sure I understood correctly.

Comment: indeed, because you retrieved a collection of businesses, and then calling votes on a business instance will get you a collection of votes, so foreach again :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try shortly.